# Loop with equation for upper limit

Tags: loops, excel, vba

Does anyone know how to run a loop with a varying limit? Every time I need to run this macro my limit changes by CountA(Column A)-2. Is there a way to incorporate this into my loop?

```
Sub UsedR2()

With ActiveSheet
Range("A3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
Range("A3").Activate
Dim p
For p = 1 To 46

Range("A3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
Range("A3").Activate

Next p

Range("D3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Range("D3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, -3).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Delete

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
'First, declare a variable to contain the info
Dim upBound as integer 'or "as Long" depending how many you expect    
upBound = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))-2    
For p = 1 To upBound    
'then, the rest of your code
```

Note#1: `Rang(A:A)` is the range of the sheet your code is in.  If you want to be more explicit you can write `Worksheet("The_Name_of_the_Worksheet").Range("A:A")` or `Worksheet(Sheet#).Range("A:A")`.  To be even more precise and sure:
`Thisworkbook.Worksheet("The_Name_of_the_Worksheet").Range("A:A")` or `Thisworkbook.Worksheet(Sheet#).Range("A:A")`.

Note #2: read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266330(v=vs.60).aspx) for the use of the `With` statement.

I also suggest you to go and read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/2687063) on how to avoid using `.Select` for multiple good reasons.

Comment: `upBound` will keep the value from `Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))-2`.  Be sure the `Range("A:A)` you chose is on the right sheet.  Then, I assumed you wanted the upper bound of the `For loop` to be `upBound` maybe it is `For p = 1 to 46 + upBound` you want, I'm not sure.